# Zabbix run script at host

Tags: zabbix

Is there any way to run script on host from the Zabbix?

for example
I got printers at company and I must change IP address on everyone.
I got script and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "[remote commands](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command)" feature.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, zabbix is not a confuguration management tool, its main propose is monitoring, if you need to run this script only once, I suggest you to write a script that connects to the hosts and will run your script loclaly, although like mentioned before, it is possible ussing "remote commands"

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a trigger that detects the printer IP address change, then you can create an action to run the remote command.  The goal of zabbix is automated remediation of issues.

If you have to manually trigger the IP change, then something like ansible would probably be a better fit for the need.

It might be a place where you could use DNS names for the printers, just set them with short TTL's and change the ip on the DNS server when the IP changes, no client change needed.